# Mysql: How can I use lead() function which returns the value of two rows ahead such that the second last and last row value do not return null?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql: How can I use lead() function which returns the value of two rows ahead such that the second last and last row value do not return null?

```
lead(column name,2)over()
```

The above code gives null value for the second last and last row because the table ends.

In short, I want the code logic to continue from the first row after reaching the last row.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one method would be:

```
coalesce(lead(col) over (order by x),
         first_value(col) over (order by x)
        )
```

This assumes that `col` is never `NULL` except for the last row.

Comment: Great answer! This works when my offset in lead() is 1. What if my offset in the lead() is 2?

Comment: Couldn't `FIRST_VALUE` be replaced with `NTH_VALUE(col, 2) over (order by x)`?

Comment: @ReinisVerbelis Yes correct this will work, but what about the second last row?? As per nth_value(col,2) the second_last row will also get the same value as the last row.

Comment: @Shieldbreaker . . . Then you would have a different question and that should be asked as a new question.